# Can I add index to aggregated field on Paradox

Tags: delphi, paradox

```
ProductTable.AddIndex('Count_Indx','Count',[ixCaseInsensitive])
```

I try do this code but not working. Write "Count field not founded on Table"

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you don't have a field called 'count' in your table. This isn't surprising as 'count' is a reserved word in SQL - it's a defined function.